# How to avoid the max. amount of input fields for JPMML

Tags: numpy, machine-learning, pca, pmml

I have problems using PMML models in JPMML (scala) with many input fields. Find a minimal example below: Load an image with 300x150 pixel and use this as an input for a PCA (python):

```
img = PIL.Image.open(filename)
img = img.resize(STANDARD_SIZE) # 300x150
img = np.array([int(np.mean(a)) for a in img])

pca   = PCA(svd_solver=pca_method,n_components = components)
train = pca.fit_transform(train_x)

pipeline = PMMLPipeline(([('pca', pca), ('knn', neigh)]))
sklearn2pmml(pipeline, "/tmp/pca.pmml")
```

In a second step this model should be loaded using JPMML (scala):

```
val evaluator = new LoadingModelEvaluatorBuilder()
      .setLocatable(false)
      .load(new File("/tmp/pca.pmml"))
      .build()
evaluator.verify()
```

which will lead to the quite obvious exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.jpmml.evaluator.InvalidElementException: Model has too many input fields
    at org.jpmml.evaluator.ModelEvaluatorBuilder.checkSchema(ModelEvaluatorBuilder.java:135)
    at org.jpmml.evaluator.ModelEvaluatorBuilder.build(ModelEvaluatorBuilder.java:115)
    ...
```

If you look at the source code you can find the following limit at the `ModelEvaluatorBuilder`:

```
if((inputFields.size() + groupFields.size()) > 1000){
            throw new InvalidElementException("Model has too many input fields", miningSchema);
        }
```

So my 45k input fields are way too much. If I got the PMML documentation right I can only use atomic datatypes (int, char, double, etc.) for the inpt fields.

Any ideas how I can actually work around this limit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override the `ModelEvaluatorBuilder#checkSchema(ModelEvaluator)` method with your own checking logic (such as "accept everything"):

```
evaluator = new LoadingModelEvaluatorBuilder(){
    @Override
    protected void checkSchema(ModelEvaluator<?> modelEvaluator){
        // Anything goes - I'm willing to accept the responsibility for my own actions 
    }
}
    .setLocatable(false)
    .load(new File("/tmp/pca.pmml"))
    .build();
```

This sanity check is there for a reason. (J)PMML is not meant for processing binary blobs (such as images), and it's a really bad idea to represent an image object as 45k double fields.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Are you aware of any other exchange formats?

Comment: If the model was trained using PIL + SkLearn, then the same combination of technologies is also the most optimal (especially, performant) for deployment. Translating to any other representation will introduce inefficiencies. 
Since this is a very numerically intensive computation (ie. matrix work), then maybe the ONNX standard can represent and execute this workflow (although the KNN algorithm is likely not supported).